# Can't find where my database file is being copied to my phone/emulator when I install to it (possibly general android/assets folder Q)?

Tags: android, android-studio

So it seems that when I run my app on my phone / a phone emulator that the database file is not ending up in the correct directory over there. It seems that the app is looking for it in data/data/com.mobiletextadventure/databases. It doesn't find it there and then creates a new empty database in that directory as far as I can tell and uses that.

If I manually copy the database file to data/data/com.mobiletextadventure/databases after I have already installed the app and then run it, it picks up the database and doesn't create a fresh empty one. This is what I want obviously, but I need it to do this on initial install rather than having to manually copy it across after installing.

In my project in android studio the database is in android/assets/ folder. How do I find out where exactly this database is being copied to my phone / emulator? It's clearly not going into data/data/com.mobiletextadventure/databases, but if I can get it to install into there then my app will work fine without any manual intervention.

Another way of asking this question might be... when an app is installed to phone/emulator, what exactly happens to the files in /android/assets? Where are they copied to on the phone/emulator and why?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I find out where exactly this database is being copied to my phone / emulator?

It is not getting copied anywhere, unless you do the copying.

> when an app is installed to phone/emulator, what exactly happens to the files in /android/assets?

Absolutely nothing. They are part of the APK. You can obtain an `InputStream` on an asset via `AssetManager` (see `getAssets()` on `Context`).

If you are seeking to package a database as an asset and use it, you can see [how `SQLiteAssetHelper` does that](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: Thanks for your input. In the end I was able to achieve it by following this post:

https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

I initially got an uknown error code 14 after implementing it but all I had to do was replace the checkDataBase() code with the code below and it worked perfectly:

File dbFile = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);  
return dbFile.exists();

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to achieve it by following this post:

https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

I initially got an uknown error code 14 after implementing it but all I had to do was replace the checkDataBase() code with the code below and it worked perfectly:

```
File dbFile = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);  
return dbFile.exists();
```